# Creating Bootstrap Confidence Intervals - 'list' object has no attribute 'sample'?

Tags: python, confidence-interval, statistics-bootstrap

I am trying to find bootstrap 95% confidence intervals for a small set of data, but when I try it, it says that my "list object has no attribute sample". I am not sure what list they are talking about, and how do I add that attribute?

[image: my code]

I tried doing 1000 bootstrap samples with replacing the data each time for a very small, 9-number set of data. However, when I tried using the CreateBootstrapMeans function in In[84], it says that my "list object has no attribute 'sample'". I am not sure what this means.

I later need to use the np.percentile function to find the 95% confidence intervals, but I cannot do that until this part gets sorted out.

Please help in whatever way you can! I am also sorry if this is a stupid question, I am a beginner in coding!

Comment: don't attach the screen. provide a reproducible example.

Comment: I am not doing much ML/DS now but if you just take `mean +/- 2*standard_deviation` should give you 96% confidence interval right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to replace the line where you define `d` with:

```
d = np.random.choice(data, n, replace=True)
```

this because `list` object has no method named `sample`

EDIT:

also the `return` has to be placed at the end of the `for` loop and not inside it.